# formValidation does not submit by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-boot, formvalidation-plugin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTMvo.png)

This is my code from javascript, when i try to make a http post pettition this send the data as http get.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#formClient').bootstrapValidator({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        feedbackIcons: {
          valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
          invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
          validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
          phone: {
            validators: {
              integer: {
                  message: 'El valor no es un numero'
              },
              notEmpty: { message: 'La Numero de telefeno que se requiere y no puede estar vacío'},
              stringLength: {
                  min: 8,
                  max: 8,
                  message: 'El numero debe contener 8 caracteres'
              }

            }
          },
          email: {
            validators: {
              notEmpty: { message: 'La dirección de correo electrónico que se requiere y no puede estar vacío'},
              emailAddress: { message: 'la dirección electrónica es no valida'}
            }
          },
          name: {
            validators: {
              notEmpty: { message: 'El nombre esta vacio'},
              stringLength: {
                min: 3,
                max: 50,
                message: 'El nombre debe ser inferior a 50 caracteres'
              }
            }
          },
          lastname: {
                validators: {
                  notEmpty: { message: 'El apellido esta vacio'},
                  stringLength: {
                    min: 10,
                    max: 50,
                    message: 'El apellido debe ser inferior a 50 caracteres'
                  }
                }
              },
          city: {
            validators: { 
              notEmpty: { message: 'El contenido es necesario y no puede estar vacío'}
            }
          }
        }
      })
     .on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
            // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();

            var $form = $(e.target),
                fv    = $form.data('formValidation');

            var link = "/admin/clients/add";

            alert();

            // Use Ajax to submit form data
            $.ajax({
                url: link,
                type: 'POST',
                data: $form.serialize(),
                success: function(result) {
                    // ... Process the result ...
                    alert();
                }
            });

            $form.formValidation('disableSubmitButtons',  true);
        });




    //Log Out User and redirect to log in page

    $("#logoutBtn").click(function(){
        $("#formlogout").submit();
    });

});
```

after dot that send the path as GET HTTP.

And this is my html form client:

```
                <!-- form to client -->
                <form id="formClient" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

                <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
                <span class="section">Informacion Personal</span>

                  <div class="item form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="telephone">Telefono <span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <input type="text" name="phone"  data-fv-integer-message="The value is not an integer" placeholder="Telefono" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"/>
                  </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="item form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Nombre del Cliente <span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="name" placeholder="Nombre" type="text"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="item form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="lastname">Apellidos <span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="lastname" placeholder="Apellidos" type="text"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="item form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="city">Ciudad <span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <select name="city" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Seleccione..</option>
                        <option value="Cartago">Cartago</option>
                        <option value="Heredia">Heredia</option>
                        <option value="Alajuela">Alajuela</option>
                        <option value="Limon">Limon</option>
                        <option value="San Jose">San jose</option>
                        <option value="Puntarenas">Puntarenas</option>
                        <option value="Alajuela">Guanacaste</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="item form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="email">Correo <span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="item form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="state">Permitir Fiado <span class="required"></span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="guarantor" class="js-switch" checked="checked" /> Fiado
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="item form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="state">Usuario <span class="required"></span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="state" class="js-switch" checked="checked" /> Activo
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                      <button id="sendClient" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar Cliente</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
                <!-- /form to client -->
```

Comment: show us your markup `<form>`

Comment: there it is the html form

Answer (score 0):

It Looks Like you have not used method while creating the form you can use  :

```
<form id="formClient" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post">
```

I have created a fiddle : output seems to be changed after using method. Please let me know if any further assistance requried :
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjap2r81/)

Comment: Yes i did it but the console shows me this:Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Jul 05 03:09:24 CST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported and the server returns this Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: @JustinZuñigaTorres you need to define in your controller a POST requestMapping entry to handle those kind of requests

Comment: my controller receive @PostMapping("/admin/clients/add") this HTTP POST